# Why does tf.cast not really work after image resize?

Tags: tensorflow

I read an image and resize it, the result is right, but after cast to uint8, it is all wrong. The output image is wrong too. What happened?

The code is below:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

image_filename = "./images/1.jpg"
out_name = "./images/1_resize3.jpg"

sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

with tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_filename, 'r') as f:
    image_data = f.read()

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_data)
image_shape = tf.shape(image)

resized_image_float = tf.image.resize_images(image, [500, 500])

resized_image_uint8 = tf.cast(resized_image_float, tf.uint8)

encode_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(resized_image_uint8)
save = tf.write_file(out_name, encode_image)

save.run()
```

BUT, If I did like below, it works well, but WHY!!!??

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

with tf.gfile.FastGFile(image_filename, 'r') as f:
    image_data = f.read()

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_data)
image_shape = tf.shape(image)

resized_image_float = tf.image.resize_images(image, [50, 50])

# This line is different.
t = resized_image_float.eval()

resized_image_uint8 = tf.cast(t, tf.uint8)

# This line is different.
data = resized_image_uint8.eval()

encode_image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(data)

tf.write_file(out_name, encode_image).run()
```

Comment: Can you show what code works and what doesn't, and (if possible) also upload a screenshot of the output image when it doesn't work?

Comment: thank you very much! please see my new edit content.

Comment: anybody can explain it for me? thank you